# Dictionary column arrangement where column name is 'start'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Normally to create a DataFrame with below code

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2]})
df
```

Output:

```
a  b
0  1  2
```

But while I'm trying to create a DataFrame with one column name of 'start' its order is getting changed

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'start':[2],'end':[4]})
df1
```

Output:

```
   end  start
0    4      2
```

I'm trying to understand why this order is getting changed.

Comment: Try with df1 = pd.DataFrame({'start':[2],'end':[4]},columns=['start','end'])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mention column name in order like columns=['', ''], it sometimes take the alphabetic order. As a result 'end'->e comes first and 'start'->s comes second.

Answer (score 1):

This is because dictionaries are inherently unordered, and I wouldn't be surprised if it ordered alphabetically in this case.

As @GiovaniSalazar said:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'start':[2],'end':[4]}, columns=['start','end'])
```

or, equivalently:

```
pd.DataFrame(data = [[2, 4]], columns=['start','end'])
```

Will force order with an ordered data structure